# snowflake - Join on result of split function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running into problem joining on the result of split function. 
The following query works, where str_field is a string field in table my_table.

```
select
    *
    from my_table,
        (lateral flatten(input=>split(str_field, ',')));
```

When I try to query on the distinct values of the split, I get an error:

> invalid identifier 'str_field'

```
select
    *
    from my_table t,
        (select distinct value from lateral flatten(input=>split(t.str_field, ',')));
```

How can I cross join on the unique values of splitting str_field? I need to get all values of my_table, so `select *` is a must (`select distinct value` isn't enough)

Answer (score 0):

To get the distinct value you need to do something like this

```sql
select distinct value from my_table,(lateral flatten(input=>split(str_field, ',')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with CTE is viable solution. So your query should look like the following:

```sql
with dist_mytbl as (
select
    distinct value
    from my_table,
        (lateral flatten(input=>split(str_field, ','))))

select * from dist_mytbl;
```

Comment: I want all fields from my_table, not only value. I can run distinct *,value but this seems like a much heavier query since engine will need to compute distinct over all fields.

Comment: So maybe its helpful if you add some sample values and the expected result because i have no idea what do you try to reach :). If you just want distinct of all your values including the original value, you just need to ignore column "sequence". Otherwise we need an example to help you.

Comment: I would like the same result as the one from the query I initially work (which gave an error due to snowflake issue with resolving what t.str_field is